# One chat for 2 number

Tags: sms, 4.2-jelly-bean, chat

I've got a Wiko Iggy on 4.2.2 Android and try unsuccessfully to bind both numbers of a workmate on one sms chat.. what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there are no chat/SMS applications which will support two numbers of the same user/contact at the same time.

If there are two numbers, there will be two threads/conversations.

Answer (score -1):

[Contacts+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.contapps.android) will do that for you.

It will also let you have one fixed primary "to send" number.

---

It's great if you only want to send to one of his numbers and he only wants to send from the other. Your workmate texts you from number X and you just have to write and send and the sms will be sent to number Y automatically.